# Trying to use HUE api but getting php syntax error

Tags: php, philips-hue

I am currently trying to use the https://github.com/muesli/huephp to control my lights through PHP but I am running into a syntax problem.

Here is the line in huecli.php that I am getting a syntax error on where [...
Here is the actual error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' "

```
$hue->lights()[$light]->setLight( $command );
```

There are more errors but it seems the [$light] is causing the problem. I haven't worked with this kind of syntax before so any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need php 5.4+ for that syntax. What are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably not running PHP 5.4+ which is what is required to use [Array Dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). To use this code it must be modified as so:

```
$hue_lights = $hue->lights();
$hue_lights[$light]->setLight( $command );
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the fix. I guess I should get updated though for security.

Comment: One wonders why there's no green tickie when it resolves a problem. Oh well, +1.